# I've a problem for Django File Upload with inline css editing

Tags: python, css, django

```
      <p class="lead" style="color: whitesmoke;"></p>

  <p style="color: whitesmoke;">{{article.content|safe}}</p>
```

I have this problem with developing django web framework. I use dark background so my article contents doesnt wiew with dark fonts therefor I must use another color style however I can't use and my articles fonts are always stay default style Please Help Me thank you so much for now

Comment: Post your complete template html and `views.py`

Comment: thanks i solved my problem. Instead I used the <div> tag, the p tag